# How to use this category factory to fill the attribute category_id of another factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following factories:

```
  factory :post do
    title "lorem"
    content "lorem ipsum"
    category_id 
    user
  end

  factory :category do
    name "Lorem"
  end
```

I want to fill `category_id` somehow with the `:category` factory.

Pretty much mimicking what I do in my view:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name,
                        { prompt: 'Select Category' } %>
```

(The categories in this case are already created).

How to accomplish that?

Comment: Why don't you just replace `category_id` by `category`? That will instruct factorygirl to use the `category` factory and assign it to the association, as documented here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/How-factory_girl-interacts-with-ActiveRecord

Comment: @shioyama Thanks that worked. Can you post a answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just replace `category_id` by `category` in your `post` factory, like this:

```
factory :post do
  title "lorem"
  content "lorem ipsum"
  category
  user
end
```

then factory_girl will initiate the association using the `category` factory, in the process setting `category_id` on the `Post` record. For details see the [documentation on factory_girl interaction with ActiveRecord](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/How-factory_girl-interacts-with-ActiveRecord).